# nvcc -Xptxas=-v output too confusing

Tags: cuda, nvcc

Is there a way to format the output of the **nvcc -Xptxas=-v** output so that there is a newline between kernels? It is already hard to read the kernel name out from the output, e.g.:

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z14dshape_U_noBigPdS_PKdS1_S1_PKi' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z14dshape_U_noBigPdS_PKdS1_S1_PKi
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 47 registers, 80 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z23rhs_kernel_big_allInOnePdPKdS1_S1_S1_PKiS1_S1_S1_S1_' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z23rhs_kernel_big_allInOnePdPKdS1_S1_S1_PKiS1_S1_S1_S1_
    576 bytes stack frame, 896 bytes spill stores, 1676 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 63 registers, 112 bytes cmem[0], 16 bytes cmem[16]
```

Comment: The kernel name is being mangled as part of the c++ compilation process, there are many c++ name demanglers available.

Comment: But is there a way to insert a newline in between each kernel report? They all get mixed up and it's hard to distinguish them apart.

Comment: I'm not aware of any commands that you can pass to nvcc or ptxas to change the formatting of this output. Certainly in a Linux environment you could pipe this output to some text processing framework to modify this output. The nvcc manual is available online including documentation for the switches that can be passed to ptxas.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: that sounds like a perfect answer to me, if you would care to post it

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the kernel name, it gets mangled as part of the c++ compilation step (which occurs prior to the execution of ptxas).  There are many demanglers available such as [this one](http://demangler.com/).

Regarding the formatting of the ptxas output, I'm not aware of any commands that you can pass to `nvcc` or `ptxas` to change the formatting of this output. Certainly in a Linux environment (and probably in windows too) you could pipe this output to some text processing framework to modify it (perhaps using `pr` or `fmt`). The [nvcc manual is available online](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#axzz355WuePsY) including documentation for the [switches that can be passed to ptxas](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#ptxas-options).